# Java 6 Excessive Memory Usage

Tags: java, memory-management

Does Java 6 consume more memory than you expect for largish applications?

I have an application I have been developing for years, which has, until now taken about 30-40 MB in my particular test configuration; now with Java 6u10 and 11 it is taking several hundred while active.  It bounces around a lot, anywhere between 50M and 200M, and when it idles, it *does* GC and drop the memory right down.  In addition it generates millions of page faults.  All of this is observed via Windows Task Manager.

So, I ran it up under my profiler (jProfiler) and using jVisualVM, and both of them indicate the usual moderate heap and perm-gen usages of around 30M combined, even when fully active doing my load-test cycle.

So I am mystified! And it not just requesting more memory from the Windows Virtual Memory pool - this is showing up as 200M "Mem Usage".

CLARIFICATION: I want to be perfectly clear on this - observed over an 18 hour period with Java VisualVM the class heap and perm gen heap have been perfectly stable.  The allocated volatile heap (eden and tenured) sits unmoved at 16MB (which it reaches in the first few minutes), and the use of this memory fluctuates in a perfect pattern of growing evenly from 8MB to 16MB, at which point GC kicks in an drops it back to 8MB.  Over this 18 hour period, the system was under constant maximum load since I was running a stress test.  This behavior is *perfectly* and *consistently* reproducible, seen over numerous runs.  The only anomaly is that while this is going on the memory taken from Windows, observed via Task Manager, fluctuates all over the place from 64MB up to 900+MB.

UPDATE 2008-12-18: I have run the program with -Xms16M -Xmx16M without any apparent adverse affect - performance is fine, total run time is about the same.  But memory use in a short run still peaked at about 180M.

Update 2009-01-21: It seems the answer may be in the number of threads - see my answer below.

---

EDIT: And I mean millions of page faults literally - in the region of 30M+.

EDIT: I have a 4G machine, so the 200M is not significant in that regard.

Comment: @SwMk: I would love to read all the entries but I don't feel like :P Did you find out the reason?

Comment: @Oscar - not yet.  Rest assured if I can come up with anything better than "that's just what Java 6 does", I will post it here.

Comment: 1. Out of interest, if you limit the memory (-Xmx, -Xms) to 40MB, do you get out of memory errors?
2. Do you use WeakReference and SoftReference (directly or indirectly)?

Comment: @Ran: Will try limiting the heap that today.  No, I don't use weak or soft references (which I can state categorically for the non-JDK code, since I wrote all of it).

Comment: @SM: What? You ran it with -Xmx16M and it took 180MB or memory from the OS?

Comment: @RB: Yup!  Of course mx and ms only control *heap* size; there's thread stacks, executable space, class heap, perm gen, and things.  But these are typically less than heap use and they are typically stable once the program gets going.

Comment: I've not seen this before, but I'm interested anyway. Can the same behaviour be seen on Linux/Solaris? Did you verify that the 300MB "Mem Usage" are physical Memory? At least in Linux some of these numbers include mapped files and stuff like this, maybe that's the reason.

Comment: @Saua: I've not got direct access to a Linux box on which to test this.  And, yes, I am fairly certain that the number reported by Task Manager as "Mem Usage" is real memory allocated to the process (as opposed to "Virtual Memory" which doesn't yet really exist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over the last few weeks I had cause to investigate and correct a problem with a thread pooling object (a pre-Java 6 multi-threaded execution pool), where is was launching far more threads than required.  In the jobs in question there could be up to 200 unnecessary threads.  And the threads were continually dying and new ones replacing them.

Having corrected that problem, I thought to run a test again, and now it seems the memory consumption is stable (though 20 or so MB higher than with older JVMs).

So my conclusion is that the spikes in memory were related to the number of threads running (several hundred).  Unfortunately I don't have time to experiment.

If someone would like to experiment and answer this with their conclusions, I will accept that answer; otherwise I will accept this one (after the 2 day waiting period).

Also, the page fault rate is way down (by a factor of 10).

Also, the fixes to the thread pool corrected some contention issues.

Answer (score 13):

In response to a discussion in the comments to Ran's answer, here's a test case that proves that the JVM *will* release memory back to the OS under certain circumstances:

```
public class FreeTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        byte[][] blob = new byte[60][1024*1024];
        for(int i=0; i<blob.length; i++)
        {
            Thread.sleep(500);
            System.out.println("freeing block "+i);
            blob[i] = null;
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

I see the JVM process' size decrease when the count reaches around 40, on both Java 1.4 and Java 6 JVMs (from Sun).

You can even tune the exact behaviour with the [-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio options](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/vmoptions.jsp#PerformanceTuning) -- some of the options on that page may also help with answering the original question.

Comment: seen, tested, seem my response on my own answer trunk.

Answer (score 9):

I don't know about the page faults. but about the huge memory allocated for Java:

1. Sun's JVM <strike>only allocates memory, never deallocates it (until JVM death)</strike> deallocates memory only after a specific ratio between internal memory needs and allocated memory drops beneath a (tunable) value. The JVM starts with the amount specified in -Xms and can be extended up to the amount specified in -Xmx. I'm not sure what the defaults are. Whenever the JVM needs more memory (new objects / primitives / arrays) it allocates an entire chunk from the OS. However, when the need subsides (a momentary need, see 2 as well) it doesn't deallocates the memory back the the OS *immediately*, but keeps it to itself until that ratio has been reached. I was once told that JRockit behaves better, but I can't verify it.
2. Sun's JVM runs a full GC based on several triggers. One of them is the amount of available memory - when it falls down too much the JVM tries to perform a full GC to free some more. So, when more memory is allocated from the OS (momentary need) the chance for a full GC is lowered. This means that while you may see 30Mb of "live" objects, there might be a lot more "dead" objects (not reachable), just waiting for a GC to happen. I know yourkit has a great view called "dead objects" where you may see these "left-overs".
3. In "-server" mode, Sun's JVM runs GC in parallel mode (as opposed the older serial "stop the world" GC). This means that while there may be garbage to collect, it might not be collected immediately because of other threads taking all available CPU time. It will be collected before reaching out of memory (well, kinda. see http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/hotspot/gc/gc_tuning_6.html), if more memory can be allocated from the OS, it might be before the GC runs.

Combined, a large initial memory configuration and short bursts creating a lot of short-lived objects might create a scenario as described.

*edit: changed "never deallcoates" to "only after ratio reached".*

Comment: Except... both jProfiler and Java VisualVM, as stated, show the combined heap and perm-gen stable at 30M, and the heap is fluctuating between 8M and 16M; so it's not my objects doing it.

Comment: Point 1 is definitely incorrect. The JVM does deallocate memory, it's just pretty reluctant in doing it. And I really doubt 3 as well, since servers generally are all about throughput, and "stop the world" GC have a better overall throughput.

Comment: Point 1: I believe this changed in Java 6.  Java 5 did not deallocate (from memory)

Comment: Yes it did. I once wrote a program to test that point, and I even think it was on 1.4. It took some time and a LOT of freed memory, but eventually, the JVM started reducing its process space.

Comment: I never, in my whole life as a developer, saw the JVM release memory back to the OS. On the contrary, I saw several articles (none from Sun though) that stated the opposite, and this is what I cited (without references). If you have a concrete test case to prove me wrong, I'd be glad to see it.

Comment: I stand corrected. However, during my tests the freeing began only at block 50 and went in a very slow pace - e.g. on block 55 (only 5 blocks allocated!) I still had 30mb of memory taken from the OS. So I argue that in a practical run I'm still correct.

Comment: As I said, the JVM *is* pretty reluctant in deallocating memory - though I observed it starting at block 40, so it might depend on other factors as well, possibly the total system memory.

Comment: @Ran: I would buy point (2) if the *observed* heap use was not stable at around 30MB (16 eden, about 14 tenured+perm), clearing showing my objects growing to 16MB, GC dropping them to about 8, and growning again, in a 100% consistent pattern.  Simply put, the JVM doesn't need the mem for my objects!

Answer (score 7):

Excessive thread creation explains your problem perfectly:

- Each Thread gets its own stack, which is separate from heap memory and therefore not registered by profilers
- The default thread stack size is quite large, IIRC 256KB (at least [it was for Java 1.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/threads/threads.html))
- Tread stack memory is probably not reused, so if you create and destroy lots of threads, you'll get lots of page faults

If you ever really need to have hundreds of threads aound, the thread stack size can be configured via the -Xss command line parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Garbage collection is a rather arcane science. As the state of the art develops, un-tuned behaviour will change in response.

Java 6 has different default GC behaviour and different "ergonomics" to earlier JVM versions. If you tell it that it can use more memory (either explicitly on the command line, or implicitly by failing to specify anything more explicit), it will use more memory if it believes that this is likely to improve performance.

In this case, Java 6 appears to believe that reserving the extra space which the heap could grow into will give it better performance - presumably because it believes that this will cause more objects to die in Eden space, and limit the number of objects promoted to the tenured generation space. And from the specifications of your hardware, the JVM doesn't think that this extra reserved heap space will cause any problems. Note that many (though not all) of the assumptions the JVM makes in reaching its conclusion are based on "typical" applications, rather than your specific application. It also makes assumptions based on your hardware and OS profile.

If the JVM has made the wrong assumptions, you can influence its behaviour through the command line, though it is easy to get things wrong...

Information about performance changes in java 6 can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/6_performance.html#2.3).

There is a discussion about memory management and performance implications in the [Memory Management White Paper](https://java.sun.com/j2se/reference/whitepapers/memorymanagement_whitepaper.pdf).

Comment: I tend to agree that this is most likely a GC tuning issue. The GC functionality has changed markedly over each iteration from 1.4 -> 6. There are a number of articles discussing GC tuning. It's worth it to look them up and go through them to see if it would help your issue.

Comment: But if GC was the issue, I would expect the profiler to show the heap growing - it doesn't. The heap is completely stable at 16MB allocated, fluctuating between 8 MB and 16 MB in use.

Comment: I'm not saying that the JVM *needs* the extra space. I'm saying that it believes that having the extra space will, on balance of probablilities, give better performance in a typical application. If you know that your application is not typical, you can tune the GC system. Read up on GC ergonomics.

Comment: Granted... but when it's currently using 30MB supposing it's guessing that it might need 800MB smells like it's not for the object heap that this memory is being.  Meaning writing this off as "Java thinks it needs it for your objects" doesn't seem to fit.

Comment: PS: I have not only read exhaustively on the theory of GC, and specifically on every GC engine for every Java release, but I have *observed* the GC behavior of this specific app in this specific context - and it ain't GC using the memory!

Comment: You misunderstand. The JVM, on the balance of probablilities, thinks that keeping this memory will be better than not keeping this memory. Based on your hardware, it makes the assumption that you aren't going to miss it. If it is wrong in its guesses, you can tell it explicitly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of memory allocated outside Java's heap after upgrading to Java 6u10? Can only be one thing:

[Java6 u10 Release Notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u10-142936.html): **"New Direct3D Accelerated Rendering Pipeline (...) Enabled by Default"**

Sun enabled Direct 3D accelerations by default in Java 6u10.  This option creates lots of (temporary?) native memory buffers, which are allocated outside the Java Heap. Add the following vm argument to disable it again:

-Dsun.java2d.d3d=false

Note that this will NOT disable 2D hardware acceleration, just some features that can make use of 3D hardware acceleration.  You will see that your Java heap usage will increase by up to 7MB, but that's a good trade-off because you'll save ~100MB(+) of this temporary volatile memory.

I did a fair amount of testing within 2 Swing desktop application, on two platforms:

- a high-end Intel-i7 with nVidia GTX 260 graphics card,
- a 3-year laptop with Intel graphics.

On both hardware platforms the option made practically zero subjective difference. (Tests included: scrolling tables, zooming graphical flowsheets, charts, etc.). On the few tests where something was subtly different, disabling d3d counter-intuitively *increased* performance. I suspect that memory management/bandwidth problems counteracted whatever benefits the d3d accelerated functions were supposed to achieve. (Your mileage may vary!)

If you need to do some performance tuning, here's an [excellent reference](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/index-142560.html) (e.g. "Troubleshooting Java 2D")

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the ConcMarkSweep collector? It can increase the amount of memory required for your application due to increased memory fragmentation, and "floating garbage" - objects that become unreachable only after the collector has examined them, and therefore are not collected until the next pass.

Comment: I am using whatever the default GC is for the Windows client JVM (command line is just javaw -jar xxx).

Comment: But if GC was the issue, I would expect the profiler to show the heap growing - it doesn't.  The heap is completely stable at 16MB allocated, fluctuating between 8 MB and 16 MB in use.

Comment: Are you using the -server or the -client JVM? Type "java -version" if you don't know the answer. The default GC is different in each case.

Comment: @Bill - I guess I wasn't clear - By "The Windows client JVM" I meant javaw without additional switches (which is -client by default).