# Difference in JVM and CLR

Tags: jvm, clr

Today my teacher ask -- What the difference in CLR and JVM. I was thinking a long time and I answered only one thing -- JVM supports more platforms. He said that isn't what he wanted hear from me. Have you any ideas ?

Comment: That's a *really* broad question. There are very many differences. Off the top of my head: for starters, VMs for different languages (bytecode vs IL); different generics; CLR supports custom value types.

Comment: This question has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453610/javas-virtual-machine-and-clr
Hope this helps!
Grace and Peace,
Jeff