# How does maximum heap size xmx influence the memory allocation / used heap in Java?

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

**A.** If I execute a huge simulation program with **-Xmx100000m** (~100GB) I see some spikes in the used heap (~30 GB). That spikes increase the heap size and decreases the memory that can be used by other programs. I would like to limit the heap size to the size that is actually required to run the program without memory exceptions.

[image]

**B.** If I execute my simulation program with **-Xmx10000** (~10GB) I am able to limit the used heap size (~ 7 GB). The total heap size is less, too (of course). I do not get out of memory exceptions in the first phase of the program that is shown in the VisualVM figures (about 16 minutes).

[image]

I naively expected that if I increase xmx from 10GB (B) to 100GB (A) that the used heap would stay about the same and that Java only would use more memory in order to avoid out of memory exceptions. However, the behavior seems to be different. I guess that Java works this way in order to improve performance.

An explanation for the large used heap in A might be that the growth behavior of hash maps is different if xmx is larger? Does xmx have an effect on the load factor?

In the phase of the program where a lot of mini spikes exist (see for example B at 12:06) instead of a few large ones (A) some java streams are processed. Does the memory allocation for stream processing automatically adapt with the xmx value? (There is still some memory left that could be used to have less mini spikes at 12:06 in B.)

If not, what might be the reasons for the larger used heap in A?

How can I tell Java to keep the used heap low if possible (like in the curves for B) but to take more memory if an out of memory exception could occur (allow to temporarily switch to A). Could this be done by tuning some garbage collection properties?

**Edit**

As stated by the answer below, the profile can be altered by garbage collection parameters. Applying -Xmx100000m -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=1000 adapts the profile from A to consume less memory (~ 20 GB used) and more time (~ 22 min).

[image]

Comment: I think this is related to the Garbage Collection Algorithm. Whenever the GC finds that enough space is available, it does not frees up the Heap space( in Case of A). But when GC finds that the space is low, it executes the garbage collection procedures and frees up the space on regular and short intervals(in Case B).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to limit the heap size to the size that is actually required to run the program without memory exceptions.

You do not actually want to do that because it would make your program extremely slow because only providing the amount equivalent to the application peak footprint means that every single allocation would trigger a garbage collection while the application is near the maximum.

> I guess that Java works this way in order to improve performance.

Indeed.

The JVM has several goals, in descending order:

- pause times (latency)
- allocation throughput
- footprint

If you want to prioritize footprint over other goals you have to relax the other ones.

- set `-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=18446744073709551615`, this is the default for the parallel collector but G1 has a 200ms default.
- [configure it to keep less breathing room](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464183/1362755)