# Does playframework release memory after a certain time?

Tags: playframework

I am new to Play Framework. I having been running Play Framework 2.7.x in production mode. Actually in the most simple code:

```
package controllers

import javax.inject._
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._


@Singleton
class HomeController @Inject()(cc: ControllerComponents) extends   AbstractController(cc) {


def index() = Action { implicit request: Request[AnyContent] =>
Ok(views.html.index())
}
}
```

Going to run I noticed that for each request it increased more memory usage. It increased and increased. At a stage with the increase of request incoming the memory using by the app reached at 1Gb. I stopped sending request, but I noticed that the app is not releasing any memory.

My question is - will this app release it's occupied memory and is there any way of doing that without restarting the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Play Framework runs on the [Java Virtual Machine (JVM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine). JVM usually does [not release memory back to the operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os). The memory can be released but it's a rare thing e.g. Java 12 introduced [JEP 346: Promptly Return Unused Committed Memory from G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) but I'm not sure this would be useful for a small 1 GB heap.

JVM is usually configured to have an upper memory consumption limit and will stay under it or throw a variety of `OutOfMemoryError` when that's not possible. You should configure the JVM so it has an acceptable memory limit for your server and let the GC do the work.