# Heap Size of a Java application is changing frequently

Tags: java, heap-memory, jvisualvm, heap-size

Allocated Heap Size is fluctuating for the java app.

I am observing in JVisualVM that Heap Size of my application is fluctuating very often. I am observing decent GC activity as well.

I am of assumption that once JVM allocates a specific Heap Size, it doesn't release any of it to OS even if the used Heap Size decreases. Can someone help me understand this behaviour.

[JvisualVM Snapshot showing frequent change in Heap Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMwQ.jpg)

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os) answer your question?

Comment: Actual behavior depends on multiple factors like actual configured GC (CMS/G1C1/..) , application behavior (lots of small short lived objects vs. few bigger ones) etc.You can make heap dump and analyze it or configure JVM to print detailed GC info