# H2 database (in-memory mode) shutdown not freeing up memory

Tags: jvm, h2, in-memory-database

I am using an in memory h2 database with the following configuration:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:myDb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
jdbc.user=sa
jdbc.pass=
```

I can see that the used memory on the system keeps on decreasing. And as soon as I restart the application, the memory comes back. I got the memory dump but it does not show any running threads that are occupying lot of memory. I am guessing this is because of the h2 database.

I checked the jmap result and it shows the following:

**BEFORE:**

[image]

[image: The result of free command]

I tried to use h2 shutdown and manually call the System.gc(). That helps the jmap as shown below:

**AFTER:**

[image]

However, the freed memory never reaches the OS/system. Neither the used memory goes down NOR the free memory increases !!

[image]

What am I missing here ? If the memory keeps increasing, my machine will always keep crashing after running for few days ? Cannot keep restarting every 2 days !

Comment: 1. Freeing Java Heap does not necessarily [releases memory back to the OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os). 2. The memory consumed by a Java process is not limited only by the heap. There are [much more things](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53451103/java-using-much-more-memory-than-heap-size-or-size-correctly-docker-memory-limi/53624438#53624438) that can take memory, some not even under your control.

Comment: So there’s free memory within the heap even though it shows 4.2G used. The buff/cache memory which is outside java is taking almost 1.5G. Will this cache memory be freed when the application needs it ?