# Does Java G1 garbage collector respect MaxHeapFreeRatio parameter?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, g1gc

Does the Java G1 garbage collector (as implemented in Open JDK) respect the `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=n` JVM parameter?

Does it respect it in Java 8?

I found [JEP 346: Promptly Return Unused Committed Memory from G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346)
 delivered in Java 12, but it's not clear to me what was the state before it.

Comment: so your question is _only_ before java-12, I guess?

Comment: @Eugene no, the question is for, say, Java 8, 11, 13, just the answer may differ for versions.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extensive reference, if that matters. but the bottom line is simple : that flag _does_ matter, to which extent: depends on the exact VM version, initial flags that are given to the VM.

Answer (score 0):

A non-authoritative answer that I found is based on https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8078039?focusedCommentId=13632717&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13632717

> Most notably, some GCs support it, some do not. This RFE doesn't say
>   which GC is used, so I assume we are talking about the default GC
>   which supports MaxHeapFreeRatio. G1 also supports this option.
>
> To shrink the heap (and release memory) a full GC is required. It the
>   application doesn't trigger a full GC manually, it may take a while
>   before one is triggered by the JVM.

So the answer would be (for Java 8): yes... but no.

- yes, it supports the option
- but only when full GC happens, which may be never

(I remain curious whether there is a more authoritative source and what's the current state, in more modern JVMs)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know a more authoritative answer than the source code and yes, you are correct in your answer - the release of the memory will happen *only* after a Full GC (at least before that JEP).

For java-8:

That argument does matter, look [here for example](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l1587).

That code is not very complicated to understand, and [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/gc_implementation/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l1647) is the actual shrink that happens.

For a much more extensive answer (regarding java-11, but still qualifies to java-8), read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59377080/1059372).

The bottom-line is that - that flag *does* matter, but how exactly is implementation dependent. There is no simple answer to your question.