# K8s Pod memory is higher than JVM heap size

Tags: java, kubernetes, jvm

We have a pod running only a JVM process. The JVM memory occupies less memory compared to the memory occupied by Pod.

Below is the output of `jmap -heap <PID>`

```
Attaching to process ID 8, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.252-b14

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 1 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 318767104 (304.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 100663296 (96.0MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 16777216 (16.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 32
   capacity = 536870912 (512.0MB)
   used     = 138141888 (131.74237060546875MB)
   free     = 398729024 (380.25762939453125MB)
   25.730931758880615% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 7
   capacity = 318767104 (304.0MB)
   used     = 117440512 (112.0MB)
   free     = 201326592 (192.0MB)
   36.8421052631579% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 1
   capacity = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   used     = 16777216 (16.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 2
   capacity = 201326592 (192.0MB)
   used     = 3924160 (3.74237060546875MB)
   free     = 197402432 (188.25762939453125MB)
   1.9491513570149739% used

8145 interned Strings occupying 771960 bytes.
```

As you can see the JVM heap uses only 131MB but the pod memory consumption is around 450MB.

Below is the JVM args

> java -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC
>   -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -jar app.jar

The Java version that we are using is container aware. 
What could be the reason for such a gap in memory consumptions?

**Update 1:**
Added pod yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-04-30T18:58:03Z"
  labels:
    pod-template-hash: 5c85b85966
    release: app-365b18d80ba58451c00b554a3429c9af-local
  name: pod-name
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "26701471"
spec:
  containers:
  - env:
    - name: LOG_LEVEL
      value: INFO
    - name: POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    image: repo/name:tag
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: container-name
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: 640Mi
      requests:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: 512Mi
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-bwksb
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: pull-secret
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: default-token-bwksb
    secret:
      defaultMode: 420
      secretName: default-token-bwksb
```

The base image is `azul/zulu-openjdk:8`

Update 2: Added DockerFile

```
FROM azul/zulu-openjdk:8

RUN apt update && apt dist-upgrade -y

WORKDIR /code
COPY ./build/libs/APP.jar ./
COPY ./docker/config config


CMD java -Xmx512m -Xms128m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16M -XX:MinMetaspaceFreeRatio=50 -XX:MaxMetaspaceFreeRatio=80 -jar APP.jar
```

Comment: share complete pod yaml

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu Added pod yaml

Comment: you might wanna read [this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506136/kubernetes-pod-memory-java-gc-logs/61512521#61512521)