# JAVA 10+ -XX:MaxRAMPercentage flag in Kubernetes container

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kubernetes, jvm, heap-memory

Java 10 [introduced](https://www.atamanroman.dev/articles/jvm-memory-settings-container-environment/#fn:13) the corresponding `-XX:{Initial|Min|Max}RAMPercentage` flags to configure heap in container environment.

I'm running Elasticsearch in a k8s cluster. The Elaticsearch container has the following resources configuration:

```
resources:
  limits:
    memory: 512Mi
  requests:
    memory: 256Mi
```

**Question:** If I set `-XX:MaxRAMPercentage` to 50%, what will be the value?

- `128Mi`: 50% of the requested memory?
- `256Mi`: 50% of the limit?
- variable in range `128Mi-256Mi`: 50% of the realtime memory?

Comment: [somehow related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506136/kubernetes-pod-memory-java-gc-logs/61512521#61512521)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In a container, `MaxRAMPercentage` is calculated basing on cgroup `memory.limit_in_bytes` value.

It is `limits` Kubernetes configuration that affects cgroup memory limit. So, in your case, the maximum heap size will be set to 256M (50% of the limit).

Comment: During the pod scheduling, the container will only take the requested amount of memory and later increase it depending on load. So In the beginning, all the requested memory (ie. 256Mi) will be considered as heap?

Comment: @KamolHasan Yes

Comment: Not without 
`-XX:+UseContainerSupport` https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_8.0.0/openj9/xxinitialrampercentage/index.html

Comment: isn't `-XX:+UseContainerSupport` enabled by default?