# Understanding java memory management (Spring boot framework)

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, memory-management

I am running a `Bulk API` in `Java` (`Spring boot` Framework). I see in `kubernetes` memory and `CPU` usage is continuously increasing.

My code is like this:

```
  function(list <ids>){
       for each id in ids{

          expensiveFunction(id);

      }
  }

  expensiveFunction(id){
   //bring lot of data 
    // process data
   //save data in db(transactional)
     }
```

So, I believe when expensive function is completed for one `ID`, memory(lot of data objects) should be released(Java's automatic `Garbage Collection`).

So, why is memory increasing continuously?
How can I avoid it, as it causing throttling of memory resulting in termination of application.

Is this is something to do with hiberante like caching data or something?

Comment: It's hard to say without your actual code ( kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) but if for example, that "expensive operation" does something like open a new db connection each time that could be a problem.

Comment: i am bringing data from external service through api. Then doing some operations with data (manipulating data to usable form) and then saving a data in multiple tables which happens in one transaction. In my case no new connection is made to db. But how opening a new connection can increase memory?

Comment: [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506136/kubernetes-pod-memory-java-gc-logs/61512521#61512521)

Comment: I'm guessing this is not a problem with the Garbage Collector. Have you tried your application outside of Kubernetes? If so, does the application gets terminated as well? Also, remember that the Garbage Collector only collect objects which are not referenced in your code anymore, so if you're referencing this 'lot of data objects' outside the loop, they will not be collected until the the end of the method you called 'function'.

Comment: I am not referencing any object outside loop. All objects are created inside loop. I have not tried

Comment: I have not tried without kubernates because it's a heavy job. But i will try it now. Thanks

Comment: Note that the GC does not clean up objects instantly but when it needs to. The GC may be triggered e.g. when the memory is full. You can use a heap dump in order to see the problem or run `System.gc()` (this is just a hint for the GC to run, you cannot rely on that) for debugging.

Comment: Also, saving data to the DB might cause memory consumption as frameworks like JPA (I don't know what you are using) might cache objects.