# Java: calling to GC takes all free memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection

IDE: IntelliJ, JDK 16.0.2

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    System.out.println("Free memory before gc: " + runtime.freeMemory() / (1024 * 1024) + " Mb");
    runtime.gc();
    System.out.println("Free memory after gc: " + runtime.freeMemory() / (1024 * 1024) + " Mb");
}
```

Output:

```
Free memory before gc: 251 Mb
Free memory after gc: 13 Mb
```

Question: Why calling to Garbage collection "eat" all memory?

Comment: [a bit related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59362760/does-g1gc-release-back-memory-to-the-os-even-if-xms-xmx/59377080#59377080). Basically G1GC releases memory back to the OS; but that happens rarely.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mind the documentation of [`freeMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()):

> Returns the amount of free memory *in the Java Virtual Machine*.

and compare to [`totalMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()):

> Returns the total amount of memory in the Java virtual machine. *The value returned by this method may vary over time*, depending on the host environment.

So, change your program to

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    log("before gc", runtime);
    runtime.gc();
    log("after gc", runtime);
}

static void log(String point, Runtime runtime) {
    System.out.println("Free memory " + point + ": "
        + runtime.freeMemory()  / (1024 * 1024) + " MB of "
        + runtime.totalMemory() / (1024 * 1024) + " MB");
}
```

On my machine, it prints

```
Free memory before gc: 253 MB of 256 MB
Free memory after gc: 13 MB of 14 MB
```

indicating that the garbage collection did not only free memory, but gave it back to the operating system.

The default configuration is designed to suite larger applications and performing a (full) garbage collection with such a low memory usage is rather unusual. So it’s not surprising that the heap had a larger initial size and got reduced by this forced garbage collection.

When I run the same program with the `-Xms14M` option, I get

```java
Free memory before gc: 12 MB of 14 MB
Free memory after gc: 13 MB of 14 MB
```

Comment: In IntelliJ this flag is: "-Xmx14m"

Comment: `-Xms` sets the initial heap size, `-Xmx` sets the maximum heap size. Both can have the same effect for this small program.

Comment: sure, sure. I mean about end of string - letter 's' at the end. In IntelliJ there forbidden to write 's' at the end of VM option.

Comment: You mean the `B`?

Comment: yes, i mean the B is odd. Well done, you removed it