# In what circumstances does HotSpot JVM's GC release memory back to the OS?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

I read in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30464183/1357272) that the HotSpot JVM does release memory back to the OS, but does so **reluctantly**.

What does "reluctantly" mean in this context? That is, other than setting:

- -XX:GCTimeRatio=19
- -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=20
- -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=30
- -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=10

to make GC "more aggressive", **how** does GC actually decide when to release back to the OS instead of keeping it for reuse by the same process?

Comment: I don't see anything here that isn't answered in the duplicate.

Comment: It depends on the GC, mainly. It's heuristics tell when to give memory back.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne The duplicate, which is already mentioned in my question, gives excellent tips to control aspects for "release back to OS". But I am more interested in **what triggers** such a release. Googling this only yields settings and more settings... https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=%5Bjava%5D++what+triggers+gc+release+back+to+OS