# Container memory usage with spring boot not low after testing with Jmeter - Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes, memory, jvm

Good morning. I have a query, I am relatively new to Kubernetes and Java (spring boot) and I am currently deploying a pod with three containers with spring boot, the question is that I am testing with Jmeter to measure metrics and scale automatically with HPA in Kubernetes, but I am getting that when you stress the memory of the containers increases, however when I finish doing the tests, the containers do not lower the memory use. I don't know if this topic is typical of Java because of the JVM, or if the Garbage Collector is failing, and I must define it in the docker image. I give him a resource limit in terms of CPU and memory in the container in the yaml manifest

This is how my containers were before starting the test with Jmeter

[image]

After testing with Jmeter, and the passage of about 15 minutes, so are the containers in terms of memory:

[image]

This is how I am defining my Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk:8-alpine
RUN rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
RUN rm -rf /tmp/*
RUN apk update
RUN apk add busybox-extras
ENV UBICATION_CERTIFICATE_SSL=/etc/letsencrypt/tmp224.p12
ENV PASSWORD_CERTIFICATE_SSL=xxxxx
ENV ALIAS_CERTIFICATE_SSL=tmp224
ADD FindAccountNumber-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/app.jar
ADD tmp224.p12 /etc/letsencrypt/tmp224.p12
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/home/app.jar"]
```

And my manifest yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: find-complementary-account-info-1
  labels:
    app: find-complementary-account-info-1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: find-complementary-account-info-1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: find-complementary-account-info-1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: find-account-number-1
        image: find-account-number:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "250m"
            memory: "350Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "150m"
            memory: "300Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
        env:
        - name: URL_CONNECTION_BD
          value: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx:1531/DEFAULTSRV.WORLD
        - name: USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: credentials-bd-pers
              key: user_pers
        - name: PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: credentials-bd-pers
              key: password_pers
      - name: find-account-validators-1
        image: find-account-validators:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "250m"
            memory: "350Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "150m"
            memory: "300Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8082
        env:
        - name: URL_CONNECTION_BD
          value: jdbc:oracle:thin:@xxxxxxxx:1522/DEFAULTSRV.WORLD
        - name: USERNAME_CONNECTION_BD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: credentials-bd-billing
              key: user_billing
        - name: PASSWORD_CONNECTION_BD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: credentials-bd-billing
              key: password_billing
      - name: find-complementary-account-info-1
        image: find-complementary-account-info:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        resources:
          limits:
            cpu: "250m"
            memory: "350Mi"
          requests:
            cpu: "150m"
            memory: "300Mi"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8083
        env:
        - name: UBICATION_URL_ACCOUNT_NUMBER
          value: "https://localhost:8081/api/FindAccountNumber"
        - name: UBICATION_URL_ACCOUNT_VALIDATORS
          value: "https://localhost:8082/api/FindAccountValidator"
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-find-complementary-account-info-1
  labels:
    app: find-complementary-account-info-1
  annotations:
    metallb.universe.tf/allow-shared-ip: shared-ip
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: find-complementary-account-info-1
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  loadBalancerIP: 10.161.174.68
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
   -
    protocol: TCP
    port: 8083
    targetPort: 8083
    nodePort: 30025
---

apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: find-complementary-account-info-1
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: find-complementary-account-info-1
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 5
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 70
```

How can I reduce the memory in use of spring boot in a container, since so I imagine it will keep increasing as it is subjected to stress

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that the difference is pretty small (~220 MB vs 250-290 MB) and you should not bother with that.

But it seems you are talking about the java app (not) returning memory to the OS. This has been a common behavior for a very long time and it depends on the garbage collector - it doesn't mean the GC doesn't work.
You're using JDK 8 so you don't have many choices, but in later versions there are improved collectors, e.g.

- G1 GC in JDK 12: [Promptly Return Unused Committed Memory from G1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346)
- Shenandoah

You can find more information here: [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os)