# Spring Boot based java application is not releasing memory (Deployed on K8)

Tags: kubernetes, memory-management, memory-leaks, jvm, containers

I have java(spring boot framework version: 2.7.11 & open jdk:11) based microservice. When this microservice is not serving any requests, each pod of the microservice is using about 470MB. We have kept the memory limit as 1200Mi for this microservice and this microservice is deployed on K8 and max heap is -Xmx750M.

I did some load testing on this microservice. On this microservice, I made 20 API around requests per second.
A consistent pattern that I have observed is that: the memory utilization goes up as I increase the load and memory does not get released after the load stop.
Once I complete the load testing, I wait for an hour or so. Yet, the memory utilization does not come down. The pod continues occupying same amount of memory as before.
I also got a shell inside the container of such a pod, I can see only the java process and the sh process running. And indeed, I see that memory usage of the pod has increased to about 1024MB.

So, a pod which usually takes 470MB (in absence of any load testing), takes 1024MB under load test, and continues to use 1024MB long after the load testing has completed.
As I can see max heap size is not going beyond 400-500M.

I do not understand why the pod usage is not coming down.

Could it be:

JVM heap usage problem, probably garbage collection not happening?
Something related to Kubernetes pod requests and limits settings?
Here are my requests and limits for Kubernetes pods:

resources:
limits:
memory: 1200Mi
cpu: 1
requests:
memory: 900Mi
cpu: 1
By the way, I am using Apache JMeter for API load testing. The Docker image being used is :  oracle openjdk:8
I also downloaded the heap dump and opened it in Eclipse Memory analyzer tool.
But, I do not see any application classes (from our code) using a lot of heap.
I see classes related to JDK and Spring Boot framework only, and they do not show any memory leak.

So, the mystery for me is : why does memory usage not come down even 7-8 hours after load testing?
Is it the Kubernetes config of requests and limits OR is it the JVM GC settings tuning?
Is it possible that JVM GC settings are not playing nicely with Kubernetes requests and memory limits?

I have mentioned all things in above description.

Comment: where are you checking memory usage ? on Grafana if so what metrics you have configured ?

Comment: I am checking it two ways
1) Through pod shell on below path
/app $  cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
2) Dynatrace tool.

Comment: -XX:+UseContainerSupport is enabled for your service ? for java 10 and above its enabled by default anyway but please double check for this param once

Comment: also please provide JVM params provided for your service

Comment: @prasannajoshi Using -Xmx750M for heap.

Comment: according to k8 documentation :
Memory is reported as the working set, in bytes, at the instant the metric was collected. In an ideal world, the "working set" is the amount of memory in-use that cannot be freed under memory pressure. However, calculation of the working set varies by host OS, and generally makes heavy use of heuristics to produce an estimate. It includes all anonymous (non-file-backed) memory since Kubernetes does not support swap. The metric typically also includes some cached (file-backed) memory, because the host OS cannot always reclaim such pages.

Comment: which means :
The total working set memory =  recently accessed memory + dirty memory (anonymous + file cache) + kernel memory. 
that's why the memory usage you are seeing are not correct ones, try using 
"jstat" command once to check actual ivm usage pre-post load test

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os) You might also be successful with `-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio` as outlined [on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/gc-release-memory).