# Spring Boot with JPA increasing memory usage

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, memory-leaks

I am running tutorial code for JPA with Spring Boot web app.

My POM is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>xxx</modelVersion>
<groupId>xxxx</groupId>
<artifactId>xxx</artifactId>
<version>xxx</version>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <start-class>com.Main</start-class>

    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I am persisting only one class:

```
@Entity
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class TransactionData {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(unique=true)
private String referenceId;

public String getReferenceId() {
    return referenceId;
}

public void setReferenceId(String referenceId) {
    this.referenceId = referenceId;
}
```

My application properties are:

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx;databaseName=xxxxxx
spring.datasource.username= xxx
spring.datasource.password= xxx
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Rest controller:

```
@Autowired
TDataService tDataService;

@RequestMapping("/initTx")
@ResponseBody
public String initTx(String atmId, String refId) {
    TransactionData tD=new TransactionData();
    tD.setReferenceId(refId);
    return tDataService.save(tD).getReferenceId();
}
```

Service:

```
@Autowired
TDataRepo repository;

public TransactionData save(TransactionData tData) {
    return repository.save(tData);
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TDataRepo  extends JpaRepository<TransactionData, Long>
```

Repository implements save method as provided in JpaRepository without modifications.

Once I start tomcat with web app, I am performing simple load stress test. I`m running 1000 rest calls to the controller, creating 1 insert to the dB at a time. There is 1sec delay between calls.

During the test, RAM is constantly increasing, which is expected, but it is never released. I am not sending any requests to the web controller after these 1k inserts are done, but ram remains the same, never dropping down to original idle value.

Am I missing something crucial here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a "memory leak" there. I think it is related to how memory is managed by the JVM. In short, it doesn't immediately return not used memory to the OS. You can find some hints here [Does GC release back memory to OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458195/does-gc-release-back-memory-to-os)

Comment: You are absolutely right - I didn`t expect this!  Setting something along the lines -XX:+UseG1GC -Xms64m -Xmx128m was limiting and releasing the memory in range, i could see memory increasing until one point and than GC would drop it to start, increasing it again with another batch of requests, etc. Thank you

Comment: You are welcome :) Well done to test with these options!