How to make JVM only use large heap size when necessary
I have a Java application running in a container (eclipse-temurin:21-jre-alpine) in a Kubernetes cluster, and I'm trying to optimize its memory usage.
The required heap size is very spiky. By default, unless very large requests are received, almost no memory is necessary. However, occasionally, large heap is necessary.
I'm struggling with making the JVM use as little RAM as possible under normal conditions, but still allow for occasional spikes in memory usage without crashing the container.
I set a Kubernetes resource limit of 1GB for the container, which the JVM picked up. After configuring this limit, the RAM usage dropped from 4GB to 400MB, with no noticeable reduction in service quality.
However, occasionally, the application needs to load up to, say 3GB into memory for certain requests, causing the container to now crash due to the 1GB hard limit.
How can I configure the JVM and Kubernetes to set a hard limit (e.g., 5GB) but ensure the JVM uses minimal RAM under normal conditions?

have you tried setting the -xms to a low value? the -xms flag is to set the minimal value/ startup heap size in java

Thanks @a_confused_student - that's a good idea! I'll try setting a low initial heap size and increase the hard limit. Does it turn out that the garbage collector uses the initial size as a sort of minimum?

to be honest I'm not too sure but thought that it might be worth a try for you. From what I understand the JVM looks for isolated parts of memory that are no longer used to be "thrown in the garbage" (imagine a graph where you have a set that is no longer connected to the main part). I hope this helps somehow :)

Per Alibaba cloud docs "-Xms: The option to specify the minimum heap size. To prevent reallocation of heap size after each garbage collection, we recommend that you set the -Xms and -Xmx options to the same value." So not recommended by Alibaba but let's try it anyways.

This might be it, per Oracle docs: "-XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent: Percentage of the (entire) heap occupancy to start a concurrent GC cycle. GCs that trigger a concurrent GC cycle based on the occupancy of the entire heap and not just one of the generations, including G1, use this option. A value of 0 denotes 'do constant GC cycles'. The default value is 45."

Found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53284728/7483211

Inspired by this SO answer, I set the following JVM args and that resolved the issue mostly:
-XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=5 -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=2

Now I can have a high memory limit like 5GB in case that much is required for spikes, but the usual RAM usage will still be less than 1GB.
Apparently the JVM really likes to hold on to memory, and even if something is garbage collected, it's not released to the OS just in case it might be required in the future.
